# finding all values of z that satisfy $e^z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to find the values of z that would satisfy $e^z = 2$.

At first I attempted to solve like this:

$e^z = e^{x + iy} = e^x \cdot$ $(\cos(y)$ $+$ $i\sin(y))$

$\rightarrow e^x = 1, x = 0$

$\rightarrow$ $(\cos(y)$ $+$ $i\sin(y)) = 2$

$\rightarrow \cos(y) = 2, \sin(y) = 0$

However I'm not sure this is the correct method (I used what had worked in order to solve for $e^z = 1$. Thanks!

Comment: $e^{iy}$ always has modulus $1$. If $z = x+iy$, we have $e^z = e^x e^{iy}$, so $|e^z| = e^x$. That should help you determine $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You were going the correct way. From
$$e^z=e^{x+yi}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$$
we know that $e^x=2$, not $e^x=1$. Please be aware of the fact that $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$ *are on the unit circle* so it cannot possibly equal $2$, since $2$ isn't on the unit circle. The whole point of writing complex numbers as $r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ is so that we can write complex numbers by giving an angle $\theta$ to the x-axis, and a radius $r$ instead of simply using x- and y-coordinates. Be sure to understand this for this is quite important.

---

Knowing this, you'll see that $e^x=2$ and $y=0+2k\pi$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (since the angle from the x-axis of $2$ is $0$ radians). The solution to $e^x=2$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $x=\log(2)$, so the set of solutions is $$\{\log(2)+2ik\pi|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Note that:

- $2\in\mathbb{R}$ and, hence, as you mention, $\sin(y)=0$. Therefore, you need $y=k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- For $y=k\pi$, you have $cos(y)=\pm 1$. Since you need your expression to be positive, you have to pick $y=2j\pi$ with $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- Thus, the only solution to $e^z=2$ is $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $e^x = 2$. Now, taking logarithms in both sides...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that $2=2e^{2k\pi i}\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and use

$$
e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy} 
$$
so :

$$
e^xe^{iy} =2e^{2k\pi i}
$$

and this gives immediately the value of $x$ and all possible values for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^z=2=e^{\ln2}\implies z=2m\pi i+\ln2$$ where $m$ is any integer as

$$e^{2\pi i}=1\implies(e^{2\pi i})^m=1$$